# How to handle Meteor Data that requires state from child component?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Switching some code over in Meteor 1.3 to ES6+ React syntax. Component requires getting Meteor data, so I'm using a createComponent to replace getMeteorData(). The problem is, the old getMeteorData used state from the component, which isn't being accessed by the createContainer component.

Old code:

```
Component = React.createClass({
   mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
   getMeteorData() {
    var mo = this.state.currentMonth;
    var start = newDate(moment(mo).startOf('month'));
    return {
     events:     collections.events.find({
        $or:       qwry,
        startDate: { $gte: start },
        endDate:   { $lte: end }
      }).fetch(),
    }
  },
  render() {
   ...
  }
});
```

New Code Thus Far

```
class Component = React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
 }
 render() {
  ...
 }
}

export default createContainer(({params}) => {
var mo = this.state.currentMonth;
        var start = newDate(moment(mo).startOf('month'));
        return {
         events:     collections.events.find({
            $or:       qwry,
            startDate: { $gte: start },
            endDate:   { $lte: end }
          }).fetch(),
        }
}, Component);
```

Getting the error "cannot get currentMonth of undefined," since it's trying to access state. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try not to send it from child to parent, it should be the other way around, parent holds the state of the children and passes it down as props... react docs on multiple components :

In React, data flows from owner to owned component through props: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Comment: yeah, I realize that, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to convert over to the new format based on the way it was being handled before. just trying to figure out if I need to completely rework the way we're getting the "mo" variable in the current code or if there's some sort of workaround for components that previously used the component's state in getMeteorData.

Comment: why can't you just put the getMeteorData function inside of the react.Component? thats fine to do

Comment: check out this blog posthttp://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes
I hope this is what you're talking about...I'm still not 100% sure

Comment: thanks for the resources! I think the issue is kind of specific to using React and Meteor in conjunction with each other. you can't really use the mixins with the React.Component element, which means that getMeteorData() doesn't work the way it should. might just be something we need to puzzle through a bit more on our own, since we haven't been able to come up with or find a decent solution so far.

Comment: Ok I see now, there seems to be a lot of info out there, I found this one pretty quickly: https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-react-design-pattern-mixins-v-composable-components-990a5411e1b7#.2h8kti4ho

Comment: yeah, that still doesn't really answer my question. thanks though!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can split the old component into two partial components: one that holds the state and handles events, and a pure one that merely displays results. Make sure to pass event handlers as callbacks to the child component. Also note how the parent component uses the return value of the `createContainer()` function.

```
// Parent component, setState should go here
export default class StateHolder extends React.Component {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    this.state = {myKey: 1};
  }

  incrementKey() {
    this.setState({myKey: this.state.myKey + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return <Container myKey={this.state.myKey} onClick={this.incrementKey.bind(this)} />;
  }
}

// Child component, renders only
class PureComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.myValue}
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>click me</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

// Decorated child container. 
// Make sure to use this one in parent component's render() function!
let Container = createContainer((props) => {
  let doc = MyCollection.findOne({someKey: props.myKey});
  return {
    myValue: doc ? doc.someValue : null
  }
}, PureComponent);
```

Comment: @aedm BIG THANK YOU !