# Meteor / React, Pass State through CreateContainer and child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm using Meteor / React, I have a main container for a Task component where I subscribe on Tasks. Now, on child components, I display the tasks but I would like to have a dropdown to sort the tasks (createdAt, Name, etc ...)

I did this using Session with Blaze, but in this, I'm using React and it looks not working the same. I don't know how to make the sorting tasks list reactive. What I'm trying to do now (I don't know if it's the good method) is to set state in App Component and send it to the container and children.

**AppClass**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getMeteorData();
    this.sortTasks = this.sortTasks.bind(this);
}

getMeteorData(){
    return { 
        sorting: { createdAt: -1 },
    };
}

sortTasks(sorting) {
    this.setState({ sorting: sorting });
}


render(){
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => 
        React.cloneElement(child, {
            sorting: this.state.sorting,
            sortTasks: this.sortTasks.bind(this),
        })
    );
    return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}
```

**Container**

```
export default TodosContainer = createContainer(({props}) => {

  Meteor.subscribe('tasks');

  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}, { sort: props.sorting }).fetch(),
    sorting: props.sorting,
    sortTasks: props.sortTasks,
  };

}, TodosPage);
```

**TodosPage**

```
const propTypes = {
  ....
  sorting: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
     {(() => {
        if (this.state.listSelected) {  
            return (
                <TaskPanel 
                    tasks = {this.props.tasks} 
                    sorting = {this.props.sorting}
                    sortTasks = {this.props.sortTasks}
                />
            );
        }
    })()}
```

And after, the Task Panel, **child of the TodosPage:**

```
const propTypes = {
  ....
  sorting: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

handleSelect(event, sorting) {
  switch(event) {
        case 1: return this.props.sortTasks({ createdAt: -1 });
        case 2: return this.props.sortTasks({ createdAt: 0 });
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <DropdownButton 
        onSelect={(event, sorting) => this.handleSelect(event, this.props.sorting)}
        <MenuItem eventKey="1">Created Date Asc</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem eventKey="2">Created Date Desc</MenuItem>
    </DropdownButton>
    ...
    {this.renderTasks()}
    ...
```

last point, **the routes:**

```
    <Route path="/admin" component={AdminAppContainer}>
        <IndexRoute component={AdminMainContainer}/>
        <Route path="todos" component={TasksContainer}>
            <Route path=":listId" component={TodosPage}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
```

Here is the impricated components ... Also, I need just the state "sorting" in this TasksContainer, but not in the other children of AppClass ... Can I distribute this state only to this child ?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually almost there. Basically, what you want is a communication between the child ant the parent. I think you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434899/how-to-handle-meteor-data-that-requires-state-from-child-component).

The idea is that you define in the parent template a state `foo` and function `bar()` which updates `foo`'s state. You pass them as props to the container. The state can then be changed from the child by calling `this.props.bar()`. When the state changes, this will trigger a render and thus updates the child with the new value.

I found the answer in the link I put quite explicit, hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey @Max G., it's exactly what I tried to do instead, but I have a problem, I can't update the state by the method... I'm editing my post

Comment: Ok, I see it better now. What is the error you have? Anything in the console? One thing I have noticed, although it's probably not the issue, is in TodosContainer, your function takes `{ props }` as parameters. I *think* the createContainer gives the props at the top level, *i.e.* `createContainer((props) => {})`. With wat you do, you are actually looking for `props.props` which may lead to undefined. But in this case you should see it in the console. Also, I assume you are calling `TodosContainer` in `App`?

Comment: No I don't have anything in the console unfortunately. It seems I can pass my state.sorting to the concerned child because a console.log display the result. But, the function sortTasks is not working: I don't have error messages, but it does nothing. Also, I tried to erase from parameter the props and do: this.props.sorting in the container, but it's not working in the console I have: sorting is undefined. I'm edited the post to show you routes, it's where the container is called. Thank you very much