# Meteor React - can re-subscribe to another subscription on button click

Tags: javascript, meteor

I subscribe to data at the beginning using withTracker

```
export default withTracker(({ params }) => {
    const dataHandle = Meteor.subscribe('publishData');
    const loadingData = !dataHandle.ready();

    return {
        loadingData,
        dataHandle,
        data: Data.find({}).fetch(),
    }    
})(ShowData);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to re-subscribe to a different Publication on a button click. I pass an object of parameters that filters the data.

So I have a button that has `onClick={this.applyFilters.bind(this, filters)}`

```
applyFilters(filters) {

    this.props.dataHandle = Meteor.subscribe('publishFilteredData', filters);

}
```

but nothing happens. It doesn't re-subscribe to anything. When I do `dataHandle.stop()` before new subscription, it subscribes back to `publishData` that initialized at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle your subscriptions in `withTracker`function based on your condition `applyFilters`. However, the point here is that you need to keep that condition in a state and access it in the `withTracker`function. In this [Meteor Forum thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/can-this-state-be-accessed-in-createcontainer-function/20835/13) this issue is discussed. Although it is possible to set/get React state within `withTracker` the better practice is to split the component into two, one of which holds the state and handles events and the other (stateless one) is for displaying results, only and to be fed to the `withTracker` function. You can also refer to the this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434899/how-to-handle-meteor-data-that-requires-state-from-child-component). 
So your code would be more or less like the one at the below.

On the other hand, when changing between subscriptions, there is a brief period where both subscriptions are loaded in `Meteor`. You can find more info about it [here](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading#fetching). So, if your aim is only to filter data visually rather than some privacy needs etc., I recommend subscribing to all data available to user and filter the data via client side queries on `Minimongo`.

```
export default class ShowData extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            applyFilters: false,
        };
    }
    handleApplyFilters= () => {
        this.setState({
            applyFilters: !this.state.applyFilters,
        });
    };

    render () {
        return (
            <Container
                applyFilters={this.state.applyFilters}
                handleApplyFilters={this.handleApplyFilters}
            />
        );
    }
}

// Child component, renders only
const StatelessComponent = ({ handleApplyFilters }) => {
   return(
     <div>
      // Display your data
        <button onClick={handleApplyFilters}>Filter</button>
     </div>
   );

};

// Do all your reactive data access in this method.
// Note that this subscription will get cleaned up
// When your component is unmounted
const Container = withTracker((props) => {
    const filters = ''; // define your filters here
    let dataHandle; 
    if (props.applyFilter) {
      dataHandle = Meteor.subscribe('publishFilteredData', filters);
    } else {
      dataHandle = Meteor.subscribe('publishData');
    }
    const loadingData = !dataHandle.ready();
    return {
        loadingData,
        dataHandle,
        data: Data.find({}).fetch(),
    }    
})(StatelessComponent);
```